# Additional Sprockets manifest file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm trying to create another manifest file, called `app/assets/javascripts/base.js` that looks roughly like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree ./backbone/tempaltes
```

My plan is to include this before my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file, which has my main backbone code, as such:

```
//= require ./backbone/app
// etc...
```

My thinking is that I can cache the stuff that won't change much (my templates, jquery, plugins, etc.) and cache-bust my app code, which will likely change quite frequently, reducing the page size to the client.

I'm requiring both files in my `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` like so:

```
= javascript_include_tag "base"
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

However, when I load up my developemnt server, only the files from `application.js` are loaded; none of the files in `base.js` are loaded. I've added this line in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(base.js)
```

... but that doesn't get any of the assets required in `base.js` to load in development. What do I have to do to get these files to load?

Comment: Did you try restarting your server? Also, inspect the html generated and see if the correct script tags are being generated